# How to convert timestamp firestore to date string and display in antd table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, antd

First, i have antd table and datasource from firestore with some fields and include timestamp field. my data is good running and show it in antd table, the problem is only timestamp value not show.

this is the code

**get data**

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsub = //some code
  //some code
  //some code
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
   let list = []
   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      list.push({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
      })
   })
   setData(list)
   setLoading(false)
   })

   return () => {
      unsub()
   }
},[])
```

**data structure**

```
[{id: '1', name: 'Gie', timestamp: {seconds: 1651770000, nanoseconds: 0}, {id: '2', name: 'Yud', timestamp: {seconds: 1652370000, nanoseconds: 0}]
```

timestamp format is automaticly from firestore timestamp field

**antd table**

```
<TableData
 pagination={{
     position: ['bottomRight'],
     pageSize: 10,
     total: 0,
     showTotal: (total) => `Total ${total} item`,
 }}
 onChange={handleTable}
 columns={userColumns}
 dataSource={filterTable == null ? data : filterTable}
 rowKey={(record) => record.id}
 rowSelection={rowSelection}
 loading={loading}
 size="middle"
 />
```

**antd table usercolumn**

```
const userColumns = [
        {//other column
         //other column
        },
        {
            title: 'Timestamp',
            dataIndex: 'timestamp',
            key: 'timestamp',
            width: '12%',
            renderCell: (params) => {
                return 
                <div>{params.timestamp.toDate()}</div> //doesnt work and not show anything
            },
            sorter: (a, b) => a.timestamp - b.timestamp,
            sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === 'timestamp' && sortedInfo.order,
        },
]
```

another code im trying and not work

> {new Date(params.timestamp).toDateString()}
>
> {new Date(params.timestamp).toLocaleDateString('id-ID')}
>
> {new Date(params.timestamp.seconds * 1000).toLocaleDateString('id-ID')}

but when i try convert with map is work perfectly

> const date = data.map((item) => {timestamp: new Date(item.timestamp.seconds * 1000).toLocaleDateString('id-ID')})
>
> console.log(date) //output : 5/6/2022

Comment: You should move the edit explaining your solution for the problem to an answer on this question instead. Users are completely free to [answer their own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and this increases the visibility of the solution to all users. You can also choose to accept your own answer clicking the checkmark to further signal that the answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE FIXED**

i don't know why antd table cant convert timestamp directly in renderCell or render. so i choose to set data from firestore like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsub = //some code
  //some code
  //some code
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
   let list = []
   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      list.push({
      id: doc.id,
      name: doc.data().name,
      timestamp: doc.data().timestamp,
      dateString: new Date(doc.data().timestamp.seconds * 1000).toLocaleDateString('id-ID')
      })
   })
   setData(list)
   setLoading(false)
   })

   return () => {
      unsub()
   }
},[])
```

userColumn

```
const userColumns = [
            {//other column
             //other column
            },
            {
                title: 'Date',
                dataIndex: ['dateString', 'timestamp'],
                key: 'timestamp',
                width: '12%',
                render: (e, params) => {
                    return 
                    <div>{params.dateString}</div>
                },
                sorter: (a, b) => a.timestamp - b.timestamp,
                sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === 'timestamp' && sortedInfo.order,
            },
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without knowing what you're passing into the actual `<Table />` component. Check the content that is being passed to the column with the `timestamp` dataIndex is correct.

I have a feeling that your data looks like

```
{
    ....
    timestamp: "",
    ...
}
```

In which case, it should be `params.toDate()` instead of `params.timestamp.toDate()`.

Comment: im sorry, i update my question with data structure example. i try with your code and keep not working

Comment: **[FIXED]** the code fixed with some code improve. thank you for answering sir